# background thread using Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

Do you see any pitfalls or issues when spawning off two separate tasks for an Oracle db query and Active Directory query and then waiting for both.

Below is a very basic stripped down example. Essentially we have an employee object that gets created from pieces of info from AD and from an Oracle DB. (called sequentially)

```
var partialEmployeeA=ActiveDirectoryLookup(employeeID);

var partialEmployeeB=OracleDBLookup(employeeID);

var finalEmployee=Merge(partialEmployeeA,partialEmployeeB);
```

At this point `Employee` object has been created and pieced together from both queries and can be used.  This has worked without issue, but if each of these calls were its own task would you see any issues from a scaling view point? (excluding any other obvious code issues)

```
Employee partialEmployeeA;
Employee partialEmployeeB;

var t1 = Task.Run(() => {
   partialEmployeeA=ActiveDirectoryLookup(employeeID);
});

var t2 = Task.Run(() => {
   partialEmployeeB=OracleDBLookup(employeeID);
});,

Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
var finalEmployee=Merge(partialEmployeeA,partialEmployeeB);
```

I did some test with the stopwatch class and the `Task` version comes back faster every time (avg: 100-120ms vs 200-250ms) and has no problem, but wasn't sure how this scaled on a multicore system.  I've not done a lot with TPL, but was curious on this approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any problems with this, these are different services with different requests that probably don't share any state.

However, you should realize that in both cases you are taking up 3 threads that are **blocked throughout the entire asynchronous (I/O) operation**.

It would be faster to perform these operations in parallel by utilizing multiple threads. But **it won't actually be more scalable**.

To do this "right" without blocking a thread and using up resources you need to treat these operations as truly async and not just on a background thread:

```
var partialEmployeeATask = ActiveDirectoryLookupAsync(employeeID);
var partialEmployeeBTask = OracleDBLookupAsync(employeeID);

await Task.WhenAll(partialEmployeeATask, partialEmployeeBTask)
var finalEmployee = Merge(await partialEmployeeATask, await partialEmployeeBTask);
```

That requires changing the API to support asynchronous requests in some form. If the API is not under your control that can be an issue. If that can't be done at least use `Task.Run` only once and use the "main" thread to the other part.

Comment: Since the tasks are already awaited with `await Task.WhenAll`, wouldn't it be better just to take the `.Result` during the merge rather than awaiting them again?  Or better yet, since both tasks return results, couldn't you just get the results as an array from the result of `await Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply i3arnon.  Can you explain more about the threads being blocked vs the parallel option? I'm just not familiar with effects that would have or when to avoid that route.

Comment: @jdross - see [MSDN: Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: @jdross calling a database (oracle, or AD) requires I/O (i.e. sending a network message and waiting for the response). That takes up a very long time. In the mean time the thread can't continue on processing (because it's waiting for the response) so it sits idly by waiting. That's what I mean by blocked.

Comment: @jdross When the operation is asynchronous you release the thread while the I/O operation is still "on flight" and so you can process other code.

Comment: @MattJohnson awaiting a completed task doesn't cost anything. It's just a call to `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. `task.Result` could be suspicious in certain cases so there's no reason to prefer it to `await`.

Comment: @i3arnon I see, what isn't being shown is before the "waitall" section is other code not relavent to the employee lookup, I was trying to speed that up or do it on separate threads while doing some other work.  I'll look into the other options you mentioned, thanks

Comment: Thanks Matt for the reply!